# How to determine the source (webpage) of Google Maps JavaScript API calls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

We have a Google Maps Javascript API project, which we call from various pages on our website.

The Google Cloud platform tells us that we have approx 22k api calls/map loads per month, and, I can view reports within the Cloud platform to break this down to number of map loads per day.

We would like to determine the source(s) of each of these 22k api calls.  E.g.

Homepage - 11k calls

Subpage1 - 5k calls

Subpage2 - 3k calls

etc

Research I have carried out to date:

1) Google Cloud platform (https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/maps-backend.googleapis.com/quotas) tells me the number of maps loads per day, but not the source pages

2) The FAQ https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-monitor under the section "How do I monitor my usage" states:

To see a traffic report and billing information for an entire project, follow these steps:

Enable billing if you haven't already done so.
Visit the Google Cloud Platform Console billing page.
Select a project.
In the left sidebar, click Reports. Use the filters on the right sidebar to view reports on your billing account.

I have carried out those steps but these reports only provide the total cost per day, and per month.

3) I thought that perhaps this information may be contained within our Google Analytics reports, but I have been unable to find anything there either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Could you suggest where I could/should post this instead @MrUpsidown?  I'm aware it's not specifically a coding query - but was hoping I wasn't the only person who might have asked where to get the information on determining source of API calls.

Answer (score 4):

It's not currently possible to see a breakdown of Maps API traffic by domain/URL/subpage in the Cloud Platform Console. You can only monitor your usage with the methods from the posted [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-monitor).

However, there's a feature request for domain traffic breakdown in Google's issue tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125464053

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.  I have starred the request as you have suggested.

Comment: Glad to hear! :)